# How do I get the binary data of an uploaded image in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, binary, ruby-on-rails-5, multipartform-data

I'm using Rails 5 and the ruby-filemagic gem.  How do I get the binary data from an uploaded file?  My form looks like this

```
<%= form_for @person, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
```

and my controller is as follows

```
  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)
    if @person.image
      cur_time_in_ms = DateTime.now.strftime('%Q')
      file_location = "/tmp/file#{cur_time_in_ms}.ext"
      File.binwrite(file_location, @person.image.tempfile)
      fm = FileMagic.new(FileMagic::MAGIC_MIME)
      @person.content_type = fm.file(file_location, true)
    end
    if @person.save
      redirect_to @person
    else
      # This line overrides the default rendering behavior, which
      # would have been to render the "create" view.
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

but when I look at the content of my file (the one I have copied into the "/tmp" directory), it shows ...

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fba2573bbd0>
```

How do I get just the binary data (preferably in the "@person.image" attribute)?

Comment: hitting `p @person.image.methods` should yield what you're looking for (I'm guessing `#read`)

Comment: You are correct!  "read" gets the pure binary data.  If you want to mark taht as an answer, I'll check it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hitting `p @person.image.methods` should yield what you're looking for (I'm guessing `#read`)